# Run On The Banks Age of Credit Cards

Tags: banking

Is the risk of a **general** run on the banks greatly reduced now that most transactions are done electronically?

Answer (score 2):

If we talk about a run on one bank, I think it's the other way around. Back then, people need to stand in line and wait for their queue to take their money out of the bank (and deposit it to another bank). Now they can transfer their money from anywhere and anytime. So I think the risk of a run is greatly increased.

Comment: Good point! My question was more about a general run on the banks. Will update question.

Comment: Is there any empirical evidence for this conjecture?